# How to enable Wayland in Enlightenment session on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, wayland, enlightenment

Enlightenment E22: "Greatly improved Wayland support"

Ubuntu 20.04 Enlightenment runs with X session, not wayland

```
sudo dpkg -s enlightenment|grep Version
Version: 0.23.1-4

echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

How to enable Wayland in Enlightenment session on Ubuntu 20.04?

I do not like default gnome wayland desktop, while running in X I have some rendering issues in Google Chrome with Intel driver

Comment: As far I know you have to compile it by your self. https://www.enlightenment.org/about-wayland   it is still experimental. Here is a build skript https://gist.github.com/SteveClement/f81ad1d4eedd5c9525b278d1502d2fcd   I have not tested it.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

The most straightforward method is to move the Xsession file from `/usr/share/xsessions/` to `/usr/share/wayland-sessions/` by:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/xsessions/enlightenment.desktop /usr/share/wayland-sessions/
```

Then reboot and select *Enlightenment (on Wayland)* session in GDM3, SDDM, LightDM to login and check

[image: E17 on Wayland]

**Details**

1. the needed related [`libevas1-engines-wayland`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libevas1-engines-wayland&searchon=names) will be installed automatically as dependency.
2. According [to ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Enlightenment#Manually) -

   > To try the Wayland compositor, enter `enlightenment_start`
3. The same is written in [`/usr/share/doc/enlightenment/README`](https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-e-team/e/-/blob/debian/sid/README):

   > NOTE: To enable wayland support (still considered experimental and not for regular end users) use the meson -Dwl=true option. To run enlightenment in wayland mode, just log on on ant vt and run enlightenment_start. If you
   > wish to debug and see all the output try using something like screen then
   > attaching to the remote screen session by sshing in etc.
4. All the sources including [Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Enlightenment#Wayland_session) say all the same about non-stable nature of E17 on Wayland:

   > At the time of writing (28 Sept 2020) Enlightenment with Wayland session is not considered stable for everyday use.

Comment: Alas, "not for regular end users". I guess that's why it does not use wayland by default :(

Comment: We have to test how stable is it :) It works, just tested in VirtualBox while preparing and posting the above answer.